# Fatal error: Cannot instantiate non-existent class:updatescontroller on line 97

Tags: php, php-5.3, fatal-error, php4

```
<?php

/** Check if environment is development and display errors **/

function setReporting() {
if (DEVELOPMENT_ENVIRONMENT == true) {
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors','On');
} else {
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','Off');
ini_set('log_errors', 'On');
ini_set('error_log', ROOT.DS.'tmp'.DS.'logs'.DS.'error.log');
   }
}

/** Check for Magic Quotes and remove them **/

function stripSlashesDeep($value) {
$value = is_array($value) ? array_map('stripSlashesDeep', $value) :            stripslashes($value);
return $value;
 }

function removeMagicQuotes() {
if ( get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) {
$_GET    = stripSlashesDeep($_GET   );
$_POST   = stripSlashesDeep($_POST  );
$_COOKIE = stripSlashesDeep($_COOKIE);
  }
}

/** Check register globals and remove them **/

/*function unregisterGlobals() {
if (ini_get('register_globals')) {
  $array = array('_SESSION', '_POST', '_GET', '_COOKIE', '_REQUEST', '_SERVER', '_ENV',      '_FILES');
foreach ($array as $value) {
   foreach ($GLOBALS[$value] as $key => $var) {
  if ($var === $GLOBALS[$key]) {
   unset($GLOBALS[$key]);
    }
   }
  }
 }
}*/
 /** Routing **/

function routeURL($url) {
global $routing;

foreach ( $routing as $pattern => $result ) {
        if ( preg_match( $pattern, $url ) ) {
            return preg_replace( $pattern, $result, $url );
        }
}

return ($url);
}

/** Main Call Function **/

function callHook() {
global $url;
global $default;
global $sent;
$queryString = array();

if (!isset($url)) {
    $controller = $default['controller'];
    $action = $default['action'];
} else {
    $url = routeURL($url);
    $urlArray = array();
    $urlArray = explode("/",$url);
    $controller = $urlArray[0];
    array_shift($urlArray);
    if (isset($urlArray[0])) {
        $action = $urlArray[0];
        array_shift($urlArray);
    } else {
        $action = 'view'; // Default Action
    }
    $queryString = $urlArray;
    if(isset($queryString[0]))
    $sent=$queryString[0];
    //echo $sent;
}

$controllerName = $controller;
$controller = ucwords($controller);
$model = rtrim($controller, 's');
$controller .= 'Controller';
//echo($model);
//echo($controllerName);
//echo($action);
    //echo phpinfo();
**$dispatch = new $controller($model,$controllerName,$action);**

if ((int)method_exists($controller, $action)) {
    //call_user_func_array(array($dispatch,"beforeAction"),$queryString);
    call_user_func_array(array($dispatch,$action),$queryString);
    //call_user_func_array(array($dispatch,"afterAction"),$queryString);
} else {
    /* Error Generation Code Here */
}
}

/** Autoload any classes that are required **/

function __autoload($className) {

if (file_exists(ROOT . DS . 'library' . DS . strtolower($className) . '.class.php')) {
    include_once(ROOT . DS . 'library' . DS . strtolower($className) . '.class.php');
} else if (file_exists(ROOT . DS . 'application' . DS . 'controller' . DS . strtolower($className) . '.php')) {
    include_once(ROOT . DS . 'application' . DS . 'controller' . DS . strtolower($className) . '.php');
} else if (file_exists(ROOT . DS . 'application' . DS . 'model' . DS . strtolower($className) . '.php')) {
    include_once(ROOT . DS . 'application' . DS . 'model' . DS . strtolower($className) . '.php');
} else {
    /* Error Generation Code Here */
}
}

setReporting();
removeMagicQuotes();
//unregisterGlobals();
callHook();


*****//
```

When I uploaded this file on server it is showing the error

```
Fatal error: Cannot instantiate non-existent class:updatescontroller on line 97
```

pointing to the line

```
 $dispatch =new $controller($model,$controllerName,$action);
```

Please help me determine what is going wrong.

Also the same server is also not allowing me to run the `unregisterGlobals()` function and    showing “too many errors for undefined index”.

The complete project is running very well on my localhost server.

Comment: What PHP versions are you running on your localhost and deployment server?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message I guess you are missing an included file that declares the `updatescontroller` class. Maybe you need to upload the entire project?

It also seems that your local PHP configuration doesn't match the remote configuration. Try matching your local php.ini with the remote server to make local testing more realistic.

If at all possible try to match the PHP version on your local server with the remote server. There can be subtle differences between versions.